# Solving a linear diophantine equation in $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations, congruences

Let $Z_{n} = \{ 0, 1, 2, \cdots, n-1 \}$, essentially, it is the set of all possible remainders under division by $n$.

**Let $\mathbf{a,b,c,n \neq 0}$.** I need to **find and prove necessary and sufficient conditions on integers $\mathbf{a,b,c,n}$ for which the linear diophantine equation $\mathbf{ax+by=c}$ is solvable in $\mathbf{Z_{n}}$.** I.e., I need to find necessary and sufficient conditions for the existence of $x$, $y$ $\in Z_{n}$ such that $ax+by=c$ is true.

To begin, I thought that it would be better then to replace $x$ and $y$ with their congruence classes modulo $n$: $ax+by = c \, \implies \, a[x]_{n}\, +_{n} \, b[y]_{n} = c \, \implies \, [ax]_{n}\,+_{n}\,[by]_{n} = c \, \implies \, [ax+by]_{n} = c \, \implies \, ax+by \equiv c \mod n.$

My conjecture is that $ax+by=c$ is solvable in $Z_{n}$ if and only if $\gcd(a,b,n)=c$, but I'm not sure how to show this, primarily because of the difficulty "translating" number theoretic properties to the case of three integers.

Could somebody please tell me if I'm correct in my conjecture, and get me (at least) started with the proof?

Thank you.

Comment: So we meet again. One way is clear : If $\gcd(a,b) = c$ then there exist integers $x$ and $y$ such that $ax+by = c$. That way is clear. The other way, if $ax + by=c \mod n$, then I am not sure that you need $\gcd(a,b) = c$. For example, if we have $a=b=1$ and $c=17$ and $n=32$, then with $x=25 $ and $y=24$, we have $ax+by \equiv c \mod n$, for example. Hence one of the conditions need to be strengthened.

Comment: Well, maybe you can consider what happens when $b=0$. If, for exampole, $\gcd(a,n)=1$, for what $c$ can you solve?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг, probably the world's dumbest question, but: how do you know that the integers $x$ and $y$ that you mention in the first line are $\mod n$ (dumb! I know!)?

Comment: Well, $25 < 32$ and $24<32$, so we can treat them like congruence classes $[25]$ and $[24]$, right? And no question is dumb (except what's your name?), so please ask freely

Comment: @TedShifrin, if $ax = c \mod n$, then $ax-c = kn$, for some integer $k$. If $\gcd(a,n)=1$, then by Bezout's Identity, we are guaranteed the existence of some integers $x_{1}$, $y_{1}$ such that $\gcd(a,n) = ax_{1}+ny_{1} = 1$. Not seeing how to put them together, though.

Comment: @Jessy: Multiply your Bezout equation by $c$. This is a totally standard technique you want to get used to :P

Comment: @TedShifrin, $c\gcd(a,n)= \gcd(ac, nc) = acx_{1}+ncy_{1}=c$?

Comment: Does the equation $acx_1+ncy_1=c$ give you an $x$ that solves $ax\equiv c\pmod n$?

Comment: @TedShifrin, even if it does, that's not necessary and sufficient conditions.

Comment: Well, with $b=0$, you should be able to figure out necessary and sufficient conditions. I didn't say I had solved your question, and nor will I. :P

Comment: @TedShifrin, it gives you $x_{1} = \frac{1}{a}-\frac{n}{a}y_{1}$. Then, plugging this into $ax$, we have $\displaystyle ax_{1} = a\left(\frac{1}{a}-\frac{n}{a}y_{1}\right) = 1-ny_{1}$. How is that $\equiv c (\mod n)$?

Comment: Don't look at $x_1$. Look at the actual equation $acx_1+ncy_1=c$. Remember that you *have* $x_1,y_1$.

Comment: @TedShifrin? I guess I didn't understand what you meant by "Does the equation $acx_{1}+ncy_{1}=c$ give you an $x$ that solves $ax \equiv c (\mod n)$. Still not sure I do.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг, as you can see, I'm still confused.

Comment: @JessyCat I've seen your discussion, and I can see enough hints to find a clear cut answer. Please come back tomorrow if you haven't got it, then I'll give you a proper, complete answer to this question.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг, one quick thing though. For regular $\mathbb{Z}$, the necessary and sufficient condition for $x$, $y$ to exist in $\mathbb{Z}$ is that $c|\gcd(a,b)$. So, in $\mathbb{Z}_{n}$, is it that $c \equiv \gcd(a,b) \mod n$?

Comment: See, if $ax+by \equiv c \mod n$, this means that there is *some* linear combination of $a$ and $b$ congruent to $c$ mod $n$. It does not say whether this linear combination is the $\gcd$ of $a$ and $b$ or any other specific number. Therefore, your statement is not true.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг, okay. If I don't figure it out tonight, I'll come back tomorrow. But I need to have it done by 4 PM EST.

Comment: Eastern standard time. You are from Florida?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг something like that ;)

Comment: Ok. By 4 PM You should have an answer on this platform.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг, thank you! Hopefully I won't need one, though.

Comment: You are welcome, @JessyCat. Good night.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг, please don't forget about me. It looks like I'm going to need one after all! I still cannot reconcile all this stuff with what I know about arithmetic $\mod n$.

Comment: Ok Ok @JessyCat I will not forget. I promise you.

Comment: Promises are kept by children. Having not turned $13$ yet, I have kept my promise. Please read the answer below. Further please comment on any discrepancies.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг, Aston Villa, you're actually 12 years old?

Comment: I'm 12 all right. But you are awake within $5$ hours? It is what, 2 o'clock over there?

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг, more like 5:00. But, I hadn't gone to sleep. I was still doing work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your answer.

You want sufficient and necessary conditions that $ax+by \equiv c \mod n$ is solvable.

Note that this is equivalent to the existence of integers $x,y,z$ such that $ax+by+nz = c$. Hence, $c$ must be a multiple of $\gcd(a,b,n)$.

Now, suppose that $c$ is a multiple of $\gcd(a,b,n)$. Then, $c=ax+by+nz$ for some $x,y,z$, so again the congruence is solvable.

Hence the condition is very simple:

> $ax+by \equiv c \mod n$ is solvable $\iff \gcd(a,b,n) | c$.

To give an example, let $n=7$, $a=12$,$b=6$,$c=4$. We have to solve $12x+6y \equiv 4 \mod 7$.

According to what I said, we have that there exist integers $x,y,z$ such that $12x+6y+7z=4$. Finding such integers is not difficult, in fact you can notice that with $x=1,y=1,z=-2$, we have $12x+6y \equiv 4 \mod 7$. Here, the condition $\gcd(a,b,n) | c$ is satisfied as $1 | 4$.

An example where the condition is not satisfied, is $a=b=4,n=8$ and $c=7$.

Suppose that we are trying to solve $4x+4y \equiv 7 \mod 8$. Then we want integers $x,y,z$ such that $4x+4y+8z=7$. However, $4$ divides the right side while $4$ does not divide the right side. Hence this congruence can't be solved.

You were close in stating equality, however, $c$ could be a multiple of the $\gcd$. In fact this is the exact condition.

Comment: this makes so much sense. I was close, but for some reason was unable to take what Ted had given me and make the leap.

Comment: @JessyCat Delighted that you are happy with my answer. Spent half an hour just attempting it, and trying to find  counterexamples.I was just wondering, how did you figure out the Aston Villa part?

Comment: I copied and pasted your name into a Cyrillic to Latin alphabet translator ;)

Comment: Oh , well, Aston Villa football club is based out of Birmingham, they play in the second tier of English football, and I've been following them since the age of $7$. One of my favourite players was Olof Mellberg, and he recently retired, and my cover photo is him celebrating his last goal for Villa.